# Configuration ldap within a docker-compose web app

Tags: docker, ldap

I'm setting up an instance of [Netbox](https://netbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) via the [ninech/netbox-docker](https://github.com/ninech/netbox-docker) image. So far I have got it running fine per the instructions, however when I attempt to configure the LDAP settings I get stuck.

I place the `ldap_config.py` as it's run on a dedicated web server in `docker/ldap_config.docker.py` as `Dockerfile.ldap` copies it to `/opt/netbox/netbox/netbox/ldap_config.py`, its location on a dedicated server.

However it doesn't take the configuration. There are no errors thrown on the web front end, and running `docker-compose logs` doesn't show anything out of place either.

Is there a simple setting somewhere I seem to be missing?

Comment: Try using version 2.3.x instead of 2.4.x